# Update url based on model state

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a basic angular app which lists events on a day. The user can change days by clicking in a calendar (angular-ui-calendar). In my controller i have a model object "selectedDay" of type Date.

Currently the app url is:
http://localhost/app#/daypicker

I have configured ngroute to also accept url in the form of
http://localhost/app#/daypicker/2015-02-15

This works great, but i would like the url to be updated and match my model object when the user clicks in the calendar.

So if the user clicks on march 1. in the calendar i would like the url to be updated with this new date. (http://localhost/app#/daypicker/2015-03-01)

Can this be done with ngroute or do i need to use another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the $routeParams docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

Change your route url to accept a 'getDate' parameter or something along those lines

```
/when("/daypicker/:getDate?",...)
```

The ? identifies it as an optional parameter.

Inject $routeParams into your controller routes and use that to read the parameter.

```
app.controller("daypickerController", function($scope, $routeParams){
   alert($routeParams.getDate);
})
```

then whenever your user changes the date, call

```
$location.path('/daypicker/' + date);
```

Where date is a string to represent the date. ie. 16-01-2015